# Extending Android's file system with virtual folders and files

Tags: android, filesystems, virtual

On Windows it's possible to write and install a shell extension to extend file system with virtual objects which looks like folders and files, and can be browsed by standard file managers and other software. The shell extension is the "backend" for these objects.

Is there a way to do a similar thing under Android? All that comes up to my mind so far is a content provider but I didn't find an info on how to "embed" it into Android's file system (if it's possible at all).

Comment: see that http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux you use FUSE library to create filesystems in user-mode. However on Android FUSE is not generally available. If you search for "FUSE Android", you will find more details. In particular this question was discussed a couple of times here on StackOverflow.

Comment: So, you mean there is no way for extending file system right now?

Comment: Not that I heard of (and I am watching this question).